# Changing position of a div each time a button is clicked

Tags: html, containers, slide

I'm trying to build a div container which contains three different divs.
The container div should slide entirely when I click on a image. So change it's margins probably?

The images are arrows pointing left and right.

So for instance:

```
<div id = "container">
   <div id = "content1">This is the content1</div>
   <div id = "content2">This is the content2</div>
   <div id = "content3">This is the content3</div>
</div>

<div id ="buttonLeft">path/of/imageLeft</div>
<div id ="buttonReft">path/of/imageRight</div>
```

I've put the container in a wrapper which has dimensions set to 1024x768 px.
The container has the same dimensions and only shows the first content now but I want it to change position when I click on on the buttons.

Should I try Jquery for this? Or what do you recommend?

I've tried slideToggle but that's not quite what i wanted although the easing suits the design really nice.

At the moment i've got this but it's not working:

```
$('#leftarrow').click(function() {
$('#content').animate({
marginLeft: -200px
}, 5000, function() {
// Animation complete.
});
});
```

Comment: use jquery/lightbox... much easier!

Comment: Yeah but the lightbox is used to jump on top of the page right? I wan't it to slide within the page.